# Is there any function that calculates Frobenius Norm in palisade? (Homomorphic encryption)

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

As I understand, Frobenius Norm is supported under homomorphic encryption. (It’s HE compatible.) However, I cannot seem to find the corresponding function in palisade’s library and documentation. Or any other HE library.

1. If there’s such function, please tell me.
2. If not, why not? because it’s very expensive computational wise? Or is it because it’s hard to implement?

Comment: Do you want to homomorphically compute [this expression](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html)? How are you encoding a matrix in the plaintext slots?

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira how to calculate the square root?

Comment: @kelala using schemes like BGV and FV, where each slot encodes elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$ , one would have to interpolate a polynomial that matches the square root in $\{0, 1, ..., p-1\}$, then evaluate the polynomial homomorphically. Very costly... You can check [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1335) for some discussion about this.
Using CKKS, there are faster ways of computing approximations of the square root.

Comment: @kelalaka I just realized that I haven't marked you correctly...

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira yes, a hard nickname should change. Thanks, a lot to read.